# Trim IIS / C# response

Tags: c#, iis

I need to TRIM (remove start/end whitespace) the XML response of a specific file, developped in C#.
I have no clue of how this file is working, because it is compiled and I don't have the sources.

The ".aspx" file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Project.element" CodeBehind="element.aspx.cs" %>
```

The response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><element><item>....</element>
```

The problem lies before and after the XML tag, there are one or multiple whitespaces, that I would like to remove

Is there a way, by modifying the ".aspx" file, using a specific module/order in IIS or anything else, to automatically TRIM those whitespaces ?

I can't modify the C# sources, they are compiled in a ".dll" file.

Comment: Why? This is valid XML, what is the problem?

Comment: A third party program using it encounters problem

Comment: Hate to be snippy, but I would throw that to the developer and tell him to eat dust and fix his code. XML is quite clear on whitespaces that are allowed or not. Adding those between tags is fully supported and thus the other program rather lives up to the XML standard. That said, please provide more info on your environment - as a solution may depend on the IIS version and runtime configuration. You basically need to get into the output processing chain and filter out spaces.... in context.... I would rather have the software fixed.

Comment: I'm running IIS 6. I'm not sure that whitespaces before the first XML tag are allowed in the XML normalization. I can't ask to modify the third-party program. I may need to rewrite the whole thing, but doing that just because of some whitespaces would be quite annoying

Comment: IIS 6 - I hope you can write C code. THat is ancient and the .NET integation is flaky. In later versions the processing stack is in .NET - but in 6 that is really bad. Any extenstion must be in C.

Comment: Trying to fudge this by somehow intercepting and modifying the response is almost certainly not going to work and even if you could do it it is not the way to solve this. Either the XML produced by the web app is invalid, in which case this needs to be changed by whoever is responsible for maintaining it as the web app is broken or the xml is valid in which case the app reading it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Damn i Love compiled source. It'll take more time to develop something in C than to redevelop the rendered XML page in PHP, so I bet I'm gonna code it again. Thanks for your indications